# Trouble with adding chars to char*[]

Tags: c++, char, arrays

I'm trying to make a quick TicTacToe game for class and am having issues with two chars I've created for X and O.  Some of the code we have to use for the assignment, so I can't have just a standard array. Every time I put them into the char*[] they show up with any char created after them though.

Here are parts of the code I'm working with.

```
char *spots[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
char player1 = 'X';
char player2 = 'O';
```

To print the first line of the board we need to use the below for class:

```
cout << spots[0] << " | " << spots[1] << " | " << spots[2] << endl;
```

which prints   1 | 2 | 3

Below is how I am assigning the value to the array:

```
spots[1]= &player1;
```

so if I choose 2 on the board for player1, it prints:
1 | XO | 3

then I choose 3 for player2:
1 | XO | O

If I add a 3rd char:

```
char player1 = 'X';
char player2 = 'O';
char test = 'T';
```

then it prints the below instead:
1 | XOT | 3 
1 | XOT | OT

I feel like this has something to do with the char locations, but I can't fix it.

Comment: use a `std::vector<char> spots`;

Comment: If you're coding in C++, you should be avoiding the use of raw arrays of char pointers.

Comment: @andre: I'd say `std::array<char, 9>` personally

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
char *spots[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
char *player1 = "X";
char *player2 = "O";
```

and then assign:

```
spots[i] = player1;
```

The types are consistent: `spots` is an array of `char *`, and assigning a `char *` string to one entry in the array makes sense — and it is a pointer to a null-terminated string that is assigned, the same as the other values in `spots`.

You might want to consider:

```
char *player[] = { "?", "X", "O" };
```

Then you can use:

```
spots[i] = player[j];
```

The `"?"` allows you to use the encodings `1` and `2` for the players, of course.

With your code, you are assigning the address of a single character, not a string, to the spot, and the printing code then reads until it finds a null, leading to confusion.

Comment: Why using strings instead of chars?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Because the spots array is using strings, not chars.

Comment: I was thinking that _that_ should be recommended for changing

Comment: It would be a valid alternative design. I don't think the space saving is a significant factor (a dozen bytes or so), so I followed the original design with minimal changes.

Comment: I was just thinking fewer people screw up handling a letter than they do `const char*` strings.  You're right that the space saving is irrelevant.

Comment: Actually, on a 64-bit machine, the space saving would be larger than a dozen bytes; there is currently an arrays of 10 pointers, plus the corresponding 2-byte strings, plus the stray `player1` and `player2` pointers and strings. Using a simple `char` reduces that from 10 bytes to 1 byte per entry, so the saving is still meaningless in these days of gigabytes of main memory. You might be right that there'd be less danger of going wrong — but at some time people need to learn about pointers too, though I'm sure that's not best for string handling. Maybe that's another reason to go with `char`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
std::cout << spots[1]
```

you are printing a **null** terminated string.

By doing

```
spots[1]= &player1;
```

you don't explicitly set the **null** terminator as `player1` is of type `char`.

You should do the following

```
char const* spots [] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
char const* player1 = "X";
char const* player2 = "O";
spots[1] = player1;
```

Comment: Why using strings instead of chars?

Comment: It's not so much that you're *losing* the null-terminator, it's that there was never one there to begin with